# Counting classes in C++ file

Tags: c++

I wanted to know if there is a software or some way I could count the number of classes used in a C++ written program.

I am doing a project, and that project requires me to investigate in a open source program and  count the number of classes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the phrase you need to google is "Static code analysis".

Comment: This might be complicated by the number of classes created at compile time from templates. :-)

Comment: @Omnifarious Analysis should definitely be done before compilation...

Answer (score 1):

If you use Xcode, you can open the Symbol navigator with Cmd-2 and it will show you the number of classes, functions and other elements in your project.

Answer (score 1):

The following Python script will give an indication.
Run it in the root of your source tree and it will give you the number of classes defined in the source tree.

```
import os
import re

def main():
    classes = set()
    
    for root, folders, files in os.walk("."):
        for file in files:
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
         
            if ext.lower() not in [".h", ".hpp", ".hxx"]:
                continue
                
            f = open(os.path.join(root, file))
            for l in f:
                m = re.match(r"class ([a-zA-Z0-9]*)[^;]*$", l)
                if not m:
                    continue
                    
                classes.add(m.groups())
                
            f.close()
                
    print len(classes)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This will produce a wrong answer due to `template <class T> ...` and `class std::string function();` being valid code.

Comment: It is indeed an approximation but none of the constructions you mention in your remark with be caught by the regular expression. If must start with 'class' and can't ends with ';'.

Comment: Your regexp works on a per-line basis, meaning that making my two examples multi-line (which is pretty common with long declarations) would suffice. One can also make a one-liner class definition, like `class empty{};`, which is also a common practice and fails with your regexp.

Comment: You are right. As said it is only an approximation that works fine for me but feel free to propose a better one ;-)